# SQL INSERT Query based on all records in the connected table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Products and ProductRetailer tables are connected through ProductId field. Products table, which has ProductId and ProdcutName columns, keeps over 400 records. ProductRetailer table's fields are ProductId, RetailerId and Type.

```
INSERT INTO ProductRetailer (ProductId,RetailerId,Type) VALUES(1,120,2)
INSERT INTO ProductRetailer (ProductId,RetailerId,Type) VALUES(2,120,2)
INSERT INTO ProductRetailer (ProductId,RetailerId,Type) VALUES(3,120,2)
```

Sample queries above insert records whose ProductId '1','2','3' respectively for the Retailer '120'. I got more than 400 products in the Products table. I would like to write an INSERT query which adds records for RetailerId=120, for all the ProductIds in the Products table. I cannot do it one by one can I?

Comment: `insert ... select...` ?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Have you tried `insert into productretailer (productid, retailerid, type) select productid, '120', '2' from products` ? (just an example, that hard codes retailerid and type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just an `INSERT/SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO ProductRetailer (ProductId,RetailerId,Type)
    SELECT ProductId, 120, 2 FROM Products
    WHERE ProductId NOT IN (
        SELECT ProductId FROM ProductRetailer
        WHERE RetailerId = 120
    )
```

The `NOT IN` clause will ensure that it won't `INSERT` duplicates for that retailer.

Comment: The best one so far, prevents duplicates as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `insert-select` like this

```
Insert into productretailer (ProductId,RetailerId,Type) 
Select productid, '120', '2' from products
```